# Sharing collections between Python and Java using Hazelcast

Tags: java, python, hazelcast

I have two programs, one in Java other in Python.
On Java I need to store in a Hazelcast IMap a HashMap, and get it on Python as a dictionary, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, maps and structures are same data structures. Hovever, python dictionary supports mix of types for values. java's map doesn’t - unless you define with object.

Comment: @dram, ok so. Hazelcast don't support this type of sharring? Just the Hazelcast's collections can be shared?

Answer (score 0):

1. Everything is possible
2. Maybe what you're looking for has already been implemented.
3. You may have to exchange your own messages between the two programs.
4. You could do AMQP, HTTP, XMPP... to send your messages over
5. Your messages could be any format such as XML-RPC, JSON-RPC, JSON, your own format, ...
6. Then...

   1. On Python side, you transform from/to your format from 5 and dict.
   2. On Java side, you transform from/to your format from 5 and some Java container
7. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Hazelcast, I'd recommend to use a serialization that already supports both languages like Apache Avro or Protobuffers. That way you can serialize and deserialize on both sides.

In Hazelcast you need to use the StreamSerializer interface and forward serialization to the generated classes from e.g. protobuf. Register the serializer and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast already has a good Python client library which can be used for this purpose. The resource can be downloaded from  the homepage  https://hazelcast.org/clients/python/

The code samples are in github  https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-python-client/tree/master/examples
for eg:

```
import hazelcast
config = hazelcast.ClientConfig()
# Hazelcast.Address is the hostname or IP address, e.g. 'localhost:5701'
config.network_config.addresses.append('Hazelcast.Address')
# blocking map
my_map = client.get_map("map-name").blocking()
or 
my_async_map = client.get_map("map-name")
please check the examples in Github
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, Noctarius shared the examples already. The only thing to pay attention to is to use the IdentifiedDataSerializable serialization on both sides.